# couchdb view/reduce. sometimes you can return values, sometimes you cant..?

Tags: view, couchdb, reduce

This is on a recent version of couchbase server.

The end goal is for the reduce/groupby to aggregate the values of the duplicate keys in to a single row with an array value.

view result with no reduce/grouping (in reality there are maybe 50 rows like this emitted):

```
{
"total_rows": 3,
"offset": 0,
"rows": [
{
"id": "1806a62a75b82aa6071a8a7a95d1741d",
"key": "064b6b4b-8e08-4806-b095-9e59495ac050",
"value": "1806a62a75b82aa6071a8a7a95d1741d"
},
{
"id": "47abb54bf31d39946117f6bfd1b088af",
"key": "064b6b4b-8e08-4806-b095-9e59495ac050",
"value": "47abb54bf31d39946117f6bfd1b088af"
},
{
"id": "ed6a3dd3-27f9-4845-ac21-f8a5767ae90f",
"key": "064b6b4b-8e08-4806-b095-9e59495ac050",
"value": "ed6a3dd3-27f9-4845-ac21-f8a5767ae90f"
}
}
```

with reduce + group_level=1:

```
function(keys,values,re){
  return values;
}
```

yields an error from couch with the actual 50 or so rows from the real view (even fails with fewer view rows). couch says something about the data not shrinking rapidly enough. However this same type of thing works JUST FINE when the view keys are integers and there is a small amount of data.

Can someone please explain the difference to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am almost always going to be querying this view with a "key" parameter, so there really is no need to aggregate values via couch, it can be easily and efficiently done in the app.

Answer (score 2):

Reduce values need to remain as small as possible, due to the nature of how they are stored in the internal b-tree data format. There's a little bit of information in the [wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Reduced_Value_Sizes) about why this is.

If you want to identify unique values, this needs to be done in your map function. This [section](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_Snippets#Generating_a_list_of_unique_values) on the same wiki page shows you one method you can use to do so. (I'm sure there are others)

Comment: Thanks for the info on the error. correct me if i'm wrong, but it looks like the linked technique is for eliminating rows with with duplicate keys. I don't want to eliminate duplicates, I want to aggregate their values. I may just skip the reduce/group and aggregate in the application logic. im usually going to be hitting this view with a key="sdasd" param anyway.

Comment: It won't "remove" duplicates from the database, only from the view output. What exactly are you wanting to accomplish? Do you want a count of how many times particular keys occur?

Comment: I must have phrased it poorly, I know it wont alter the database.